# Attribute cannot be cast from system.int to system.string in C# via Ajax Request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class with three attributes:

int idAreaCode

int areaCode

int City_idCity (this represents a foreign key of table "City", but it is not the problem.

What happens:
I created a method which is called in an Ajax request on page with this structure:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddNewAreaCode(AreaCode model)
    {
        try
        {
        AreaCodeBLL oAreaCode = new AreaCodeBLL { areaCode = model };
        if (oAreaCode.Save()) return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = PlatformLib.Classes.Common.CommonMessages.ConstGeneralErrors;
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My Ajax request

```
function submitNewAreaCode(dataContent) {
var City_idCity = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#City_idCity").attr("value");
var areaCode = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#areaCode").attr("value");
var idAreaCode = 0;
var model = JSON.stringify({ "idAreaCode": idAreaCode, "areaCode": areaCode, "City_idCity": City_idCity });
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Address/AddNewAreaCode',
    data: model,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    //dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //window.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        console.log(err.Message);
    }
});
```

}

I'm in a trouble with this object. I tested with the initial structure, but the server returns a cast error from System.Int32 to System.String.

If I change the type of attribute "areaCode" to String, the Controller Method is called correctly. But this attribute **MUST BE** an integer!

Am I forgetting something?

**EDIT**

This error occurs in the Ajax return:
[image]

If I change the type of areaCode attribute in my class to string, it not happen.

**EDIT 2**
My AreaCode Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using PlatformLib.Classes.Common;
using PlatformLib.DAL.Address;

namespace PlatformLib.Classes.Address
{
    public class AreaCode
    {
        #region Attributes
        [TableColumnAttribute("idAreaCode")]
        [ProcedureParamAttribute("@idAreaCode", SqlDbType.Int)]
        [Display(Name = CommonMessages.ConstIdAreaCode)]
        public int idAreaCode { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Area code
        /// </summary>
        [TableColumnAttribute("areaCode")]
        [ProcedureParamAttribute("@areaCode", SqlDbType.Int)]
        [Display(Name = CommonMessages.ConstAreaCode)]
        [StringLength(72, ErrorMessage=CommonMessages.ConstErrorMsgStringMaxSizeReached)]
        public int areaCode { get; set; }

        [TableColumnAttribute("City_idCity")]
        [ProcedureParamAttribute("@City_idCity", SqlDbType.Int)]
        [Display(Name = CommonMessages.ConstIdCity)]
        public int City_idCity { get; set; }

        public void Load()
        {
            AreaCodeDAL oDAL = new AreaCodeDAL();
            AreaCode oArea = oDAL.Select(this);
            this.areaCode = oArea.areaCode;
            this.City_idCity = oArea.City_idCity;
            this.idAreaCode = oArea.idAreaCode;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `areaCode` in `submitNewAreaCode`? Also, do you mean _property_ instead of attribute?

Comment: @petelids The value is the content of TextBox, which only receive integer numbers.

Comment: What happens in `oAreaCode.Save()`?

Comment: @petelids This method saves the change, based on idAreaCode. If passed zero, it will insert a new record. But my problem is to call the AddNewAreaCode method. Entering there, the rest of my flow runs correctly.

Comment: Try removing the `StringLength` attribute from `areaCode`. I don't think that will work on an `int`.

Comment: Oh man... Damnit! A stupid detail was delaying my job... It worked now, after removing the StringLenght attribute. Tks, guy!

Comment: Glad you sorted it. I've added it as an answer so you can mark it as complete if you want to :)

Comment: I did it! Again, tks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`StringLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute should only be applied to a `string` property but you have one on your `areaCode` property which is an `int`. Removing the attribute from `areaCode` will fix your problem.

```
[TableColumnAttribute("areaCode")]
[ProcedureParamAttribute("@areaCode", SqlDbType.Int)]
[Display(Name = CommonMessages.ConstAreaCode)]
//[StringLength(72, ErrorMessage=CommonMessages.ConstErrorMsgStringMaxSizeReached)]
public int areaCode { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code returns a string:
    var areaCode = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#areaCode").attr("value");

that produces the following (Example):

```
"{"idAreaCode":0,"areaCode":"2","City_idCity":"1"}"
```

Change it to

```
var areaCode = parseInt($(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#areaCode").attr("value"));
```

and the result will be:

```
"{"idAreaCode":"0","areaCode":2,"City_idCity":null}"
```

Comment: I tried here with your suggestion, but it returned the same result. The error is the following: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: are you getting the error in the server or in the javascript? Can you copy/paste your javascript code to the chrome console and then query the model and post the result here?

Comment: See the edit of this post, I uploaded the error print.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked, but I commented all things inside your AddNewAreaCode() except the return Json(...) and I can see my values. Try to hardcode the javascript values of variables to var City_idCity = 0; var areaCode = 1;var idAreaCode = 2;

Comment: I don't know what's happening, I tried as you said, but it still is returning the error...

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in the Load() method? Why do you have a StringLength in the areaCode that is an int? Maybe the problem is n the dataContent you pass in he submitNewAreaCode(dataContent). Say something or I will post my code

Comment: My Load() method loads an object based on its ID. All methods were tested in Unit Tests and worked fine. But I didn't know this parseInt() method in jQuery. Your answer didn't solved my problem, but was so useful to me.